# Rolling polygon

Tags: processing, polygon

I have created a polygon in processing using vertex() fucntion

Now I want to roll this polygon as shown in the image ..link below. Please help me.

```
void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
}

float angle=0, yl, dx=0;
int N=4, r=50;
void draw() {
  background(-1);
  if (left) dx-=1; 
  if (right) dx+=1;
  if (mousePressed==true)N = (int)map(mouseX, 0, width, 3, 25);
  translate(width>>1, height>>1);
  line(-width/2, 0, width/2, 0);
  float innerAngle = PI-TWO_PI/N; 
  translate(0, -r);
  rotate(PI/2);
  //------------------------------------------
  float theta  = acos(dx/r);
  float dy = r*sin(theta);
  //float dx = r*cos(theta);
  //------------------------------------------
  pushMatrix();
  translate(dx, dy);
  rotate(PI/2-theta);
  polygon(N, r);
  popMatrix();
}

void polygon(int edges, int r) {
  noFill();
  beginShape();
  for (int i=0; i<edges; i++) {
    float x = r*cos(i*TWO_PI/edges);
    float y = r*sin(i*TWO_PI/edges);
    line(0, 0, x, y);
    vertex(x, y);
    pushStyle();
    fill(0);
    text(i+1, x, y);
    popStyle();
  }
  endShape(CLOSE);
  ellipse(0, 0, 2, 2);
}

boolean  right=false, left=false;
void keyPressed() {
  if (key==CODED) {
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      left=true;
    }
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      right=true;
    }
  }
}

void keyReleased() {
  left=false;
  right=false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: I am not able to think how to make my polygon roll and move together something like here http://tube.geogebra.org/student/m2874

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have copied this code and I don't remember who's it is. I got it from the Procesing forum. I think it might be Amnon's code, but not sure maybe Quark's. Anyway it was an answer to a question in the forum that I can't find anymore. It might help you getting started. It is rotating a rectangle though :

```java
Square square;
void setup() {  
  size(600, 200);  
  smooth();  
  square = new Square(30, 100, 40, 60, 0.05);
}
void draw() {  
  background(200);  
  line(0, square.y+square.h/2, width, square.y+square.h/2);  
  square.update();  
  square.display();
}
class Square {  
  float x, y, w, h, speed, rX, rY;  
  PVector[] p;  
  Square(float x, float y, float w, float h, float speed) {    
    this.x = x;    
    this.y = y;    
    this.w = w;    
    this.h = h;    
    this.speed = speed;       
    // corner points   
    p = new PVector[4];    
    p[0] = new PVector(-w/2, -h/2);    
    p[1] = new PVector(w/2, -h/2);    
    p[2] = new PVector(w/2, h/2);    
    p[3] = new PVector(-w/2, h/2);
  }  
  void update() {   
    // rotate corners and find most-bottom corner   
    PVector bott = new PVector();    
    for (int i = 0; i<p.length; i++) {      
      p[i].rotate(speed);          
      if (p[i].y > bott.y) {        
        bott = p[i];
      }
    }        
    // calculate x-value    
    float lastrX = rX;    
    rX = x + (w/2 - bott.x);    
    if (lastrX > rX) {      
      x += (lastrX - rX);      
      rX += (lastrX - rX);
    }    // calculate y-value    
    rY = y - (bott.y-h/2);
  } 
  // draw rectangle    
  void display() {    
    pushMatrix();    
    translate(rX, rY);    
    beginShape();    
    vertex(p[0].x, p[0].y);    
    vertex(p[1].x, p[1].y);    
    vertex(p[2].x, p[2].y);    
    vertex(p[3].x, p[3].y);    
    vertex(p[0].x, p[0].y);    
    endShape();    
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the polygon clockwise around the right most vertex touching the "ground" until a different vertex is touching the ground. Then rotate the polygon around that vertex repeat as desired.

Tip: Make the polygon level with the ground before you rotate a new vertex (ignoring the first vertex to be rotated). Otherwise, the vertex being rotated around might be above or below the ground.

Note: Doesn't looking like you are rotating it around any specific vertex and thus are probably just rotating it around the center of the polygon which is doable, but far more complicated to work out.

Comment: I have tried this implmenting earlier but it didn't work out well. Would you please illustrate the code ?

This is how I wanted http://tube.geogebra.org/student/m2874